# How to replicate my git branch with visual studio project in a new system and work paralelly

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, clone, git-branch

I am currently working on a visual studio project from my laptop with a particual branch in Git. I commit and push my changes to my remote branch at the end of the day.

Now I have set up another system with visual studio, which I want to use sometimes as well for working on the same project/ branch.

How can this be done such that both my laptop and system can be used alternatively.

I understand that till I commit my changes on one system, the other would not be updated with these changes.

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

**Just some general principles**

You could set up a remote (bare) repository, it's very easy with platforms like github, gitlab, bitbucket, and the like.

You'd work from any of your two computers, then `push` to the remote repo when you're done.

Then, to resume work from the second machine, you'd `pull` your latest commits and would then have the latest changes to build on top of.

I won't try to write a full tutorial here of course, it's not the place for that. You can rely on the excellent guides these platforms propose to setup a repository there.

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt reply. I'm quite new to git concept... would be great if you could elaborate a bit on how i can get that done.     Sorry for the trouble, but it would be very helpful. Thanks again  :)

Comment: I'm using VS 2019 Community edition and I have the Github desktop application as well...

Comment: @veniwro I was answering on the principle. For the details, as you seem to already have a foot in the github world as opposed to its competitors, see the [github guide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line). Very well done.

Comment: sure... would you probably have a link I could use? Most of what I come across show how to clone a whole repository... I'm not sure if I need to do that or only my branch...

Comment: @veniwro I'd like to help but it's hard to know where to start... did you try doing a few tutorials to get the basics? It's in fact not that hard. I'd suggest checking the links in our [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info).

Comment: Most probably it is quite easy... i guess I'm uncertain of how to ensure I clone just my branch or if it is okay to clone the entire repository....And I'll be more comfortable to do it through the GitHub app or VS rather than through command prompt....

Comment: Clone the whole repo. But if you're more comfortable with a software suite, of course you'd have to check *their* doc on the subject. Also, in case you prefer video guides, there are [some of these](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLg7s6cbtAD15HBa4C41jhT9YQs5bZumTE) for github.

Comment: Thanks a lot !.. got it done through visual studio clone option ! Thanks once again for your inputs :)